# Position of stress in English words derived from New Latin

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, latin

In [another thread on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/851/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-caribbean) a question was asked about the pronunciation of the word *Caribbean;* that discussion focused on the position of the accent. Cognate forms of the word *Caribbean* have existed in European languages and English since the discovery of the New World.  The New Latin form *caribbaeus,*  available for international communication in Latin, provides a plausible answer to the question: *ae* is a diphthong in Latin, and for metrical purposes diphthongs are treated as long vowels. A long vowel in the penultimate position of a word gets the stress accent.

But is it appropriate in contemporary spoken English to rely on such historical usage? And in particular, what sense does it make to rely on the historical position of the accent when, in everyday speech, the rules for the pronunciation of the Latin vowels are ignored? Note that in typical English usage the *e* in *Caribbean* is pronounced as the *e* in the word *me* — in other words like the Latin *i.* And that Latin *i* is notorious for becoming a weak vowel, for shifting from long to short. And isn’t that what has happened when *Caribbean* is pronounced "ca-RIB-be-en"?

In other words, if you insist that the accent be on the  *be* of *Caribbean,* wouldn’t it make just as much sense to insist on using the  Latin vowel sound for the same syllable?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I've tidied up the paragraphs which Markdown doesn't really help with, and added use-mention of words. You may want to add an "American-English" tag if that's relevant. The British pronunciation and AmE pronunciation appear to differ. And what do you mean by "the Latin vowel sound for the same syllable"? This is where IPA is necessary (and not just useful).

Comment: The _etymological fallacy_ is a genetic fallacy that holds, erroneously, that the present-day meaning of a word or phrase should necessarily be similar to its historical meaning. This is a linguistic misconception. // For centuries there has been a movement to _reform the spelling_ of English. It seeks to change English spelling so that it is more consistent, matches pronunciation better, and follows the alphabetic principle.... Some spelling reform proposals have been adopted partially or temporarily.... [Wikipediax2] I think pronunciation is even less likely to conform to 'the old ways'.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. As far as I can tell from searching Google books, the New Latin forms *caribbaea* and *caribbaeus* only date to the mid-18th century, long after *Caribbean* was first used in English. So the New Latin seems to be derived from the English (it certainly doesn't seem to be derived from the French, Spanish, Italian, or German, as those are all spelled somewhat differently).

Comment: @ Andrew I avoided the use of IPA there so the discussion would not become focused on the specific nature of the vowel sound in question. The important thing was to note that that vowel sound was a long vowel sound. Any long vowel sound in the penultimate syllable would have caused that syllable to be stressed.

Comment: @Shor If my premise is flawed, it's because the dictionary I'm using is flawed: Webster's 7th, in the definition of Caribbean, cites Caribbaeus for the etymology.

Comment: Non-low vowels in English are long (or tensed) when before another vowel.  The "e" of Caribbean is before "a", so it's long, regardless of whether it's stressed.  Like "area", "diarrhea", "arboreal", "piteous", "igneous".

Comment: @Jim: the OED says the derivation is either *Caribee + an* or *Carib + ean*. No mention made of Latin. I see no reason why the word would have had to go through Latin to reach English, rather than coming directly from the Spanish. Sailors would have spoken English and Spanish, not Latin.

Answer (score 0):

I question whether it is really true that Caribbean was borrowed from a form with [ai] in the next last syllable.  There is an old British tradition of pronouncing Latin words spelled with "ae" as [i] ("ee"), as in alumnae, so maybe the Latin original with "ae" was actually pronounced with [i] at the time Caribbean was borrowed.

I tried to track down online the source of this British tradition of pronouncing Latin "ae" as [i], but I couldn't find it.  Maybe another reader knows.

I agree that if there has been a continuous tradition of pronouncing words that were originally borrowed, it would make more sense to treat them explicitly as loan words, in describing their current pronunciations.

Comment: Actually, from the chronology of their first uses I can find in Google Books, it looks like the New Latin forms *caribbaeus* and *caribbaea* were derived from the English *Caribbean*, and not the other way around.

Comment: There's actually an entire regular system of pronouncing vowels in words taken from Latin according to the English Great Vowel shift, which can be seen in many common latinate words like Caesar, algae, etc. In these words, the rules for latin vowel quality are not ignored so much as replaced by a modified system. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin

Comment: @Shor That you were able to trace caribbaea and caribbaeus to the mid-18th century is not surprising: that's when internationally used standardized formal scientific nomenclature for plants and animals began. Searching the non-standardized pre-Linnaean literature is harder (the voice of experience speaking here) but surely the word must have been used before Linnaeus.

Comment: @Greg Google "Traditional English pronunciation of Latin".